# Change Custom Android Theme Dynamically

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile, android-theme

I have a few customer theme's in my style.xml file. I want to change the theme upon clicking a button in an alertDialog.

When I try to change the theme, I get an error that the class can't be inflated.  I verified that the minimum API is at least 21 which from other posts has to be done.

Here is my code:

**style.xml**

```xml
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.easter" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="color_1">@color/easter_color_1</item>
        <item name="color_2">@color/easter_color_2</item>
        <item name="color_3">@color/easter_color_3</item>
        <item name="color_4">@color/easter_color_4</item>
        <item name="color_5">@color/easter_color_5</item>
    </style>

    <style name="soft" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="color_1">@color/soft_color_1</item>
        <item name="color_2">@color/soft_color_2</item>
        <item name="color_3">@color/soft_color_3</item>
        <item name="color_4">@color/soft_color_4</item>
        <item name="color_5">@color/soft_color_5</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.girl" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="color_1">@color/girl_color_1</item>
        <item name="color_2">@color/girl_color_2</item>
        <item name="color_3">@color/girl_color_3</item>
        <item name="color_4">@color/girl_color_4</item>
        <item name="color_5">@color/girl_color_5</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.summer" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="color_1">@color/summer_color_1</item>
        <item name="color_2">@color/summer_color_2</item>
        <item name="color_3">@color/summer_color_3</item>
        <item name="color_4">@color/summer_color_4</item>
        <item name="color_5">@color/summer_color_5</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.warm" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="color_1">@color/warm_color_1</item>
        <item name="color_2">@color/warm_color_2</item>
        <item name="color_3">@color/warm_color_3</item>
        <item name="color_4">@color/warm_color_4</item>
        <item name="color_5">@color/warm_color_5</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I am trying to dynamically change the theme using the following code:

```java
@Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
    switch (item) {
        case 0:
            themeUtils.changeToTheme(AdminSettings.this, themeUtils.EASTER);
            break;
        case 1:
            themeUtils.changeToTheme(AdminSettings.this, themeUtils.SOFT);
            break;
        case 2:
            themeUtils.changeToTheme(AdminSettings.this, themeUtils.GIRL);
            break;
        case 3:
            themeUtils.changeToTheme(AdminSettings.this, themeUtils.SUMMER);
            break;
        case 4:
            themeUtils.changeToTheme(AdminSettings.this, themeUtils.WARM);
            break;
    }
}
```

**themeUtils.class**

```java
package sourceCode;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.projects.fbgrecojr.vamoose.R;

/**
 * Created by fbgrecojr on 8/26/15.
 */
public class themeUtils {

    private static int cTheme;

    public final static int EASTER = 0;
    public final static int SOFT = 1;
    public final static int GIRL = 2;
    public final static int SUMMER = 3;
    public final static int WARM = 4;

    public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme) {
        cTheme = theme;
        activity.finish();

        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
    }

    public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity) {
        switch (cTheme) {
            default:
            case EASTER:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_easter);
                break;
            case SOFT:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.soft);
                break;
            case GIRL:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_girl);
                break;
            case SUMMER:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_summer);
                break;
            case WARM:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_warm);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

finally, in my `onCreate()` method in the activity that I want to change the theme I have this code:

```java
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    themeUtils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_settings);
    ....
}
```

How can I fix this??